# Javascript Target Window Losing Name

Tags: javascript

I am opening a link in a new window w/ a tampermonkey script when a certain page loads:

```
window.open("http://www.google.com/search?q="+searchText+"", "myWindow",false);
```

This opens a child window with the correct google results.  Then when I reload the parent window, the same script runs.  It should display the new results in the 'myWindow' child window, but it doesn't work.

Right now, it spawns a completely new child window on each parent window reload.  The name of the new child window is no longer 'myWindow' after google returns the results.  How can I fix this?